# Python os.path.dirname("path") bug - does not return parent directory when path terminated by "/"

Tags: python, operating-system, os.path, dirname

In some cases a directory path will be terminated
with a "/" character to denote that the path in
question is a directory and not a file.

The os.path.dirname function is supposed to return
the parent directory name, but when a "/" is present
on the end of the path string the directory itself
and not the parent directory is returned.

EXAMPLE:

```
>>> os.path.dirname("/a/b/c/d/e/f")
'/a/b/c/d/e'                       <----- correct

>>> os.path.dirname("/a/b/c/d/e/f/")
'/a/b/c/d/e/f'     <-----------------should be '/a/b/c/d/e'
```

Seems like what is needed is a test for a "/" character
like this:

if s[-1] == "/":
      s=s[:-1]

Is there a reason that this function acts the way it does,
or is this an actual bug?  If this is a bug, how do I file
it or can someone file this?

Comment: maybe you can do "/a/b/c/d/e/f/".rstrip("/") before getting the dirname.

Comment: Thanks, that is another way to do - if s[-1] == "/": s=s[:-1] .  The help doc for this function is worded imprecisely since it talks "directory name" but it really should say "parent directory" name since it does not know or do any checking on what it is handed, it just treats a string blindly as a path, and as the UNIX "dirname" command does.  A trailing "/" character can only mean one thing, i.e. that the string to the left indicates a directory and not a file, so returning the "directory component" of that string would be actually returning the file name itself.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `os.path.dirname` is not supposed to return the parent directory name at all. From the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html):

> os.path.dirname(path)
>
> Return the directory name of pathname path. This
>   is the first element of the pair returned by passing path to the
>   function split().

Or you can just use the built-in help function:

```
>>> import os
>>> help(os.path.dirname)
Help on function dirname in module ntpath:

dirname(p)
    Returns the directory component of a pathname
```

Basically it looks like given a path, dirname tries to find the directory componenet of it. For a file, sure that means the directory in which it resides, but for a directory, it seems logical to me to return the directory itself.

Comment: The documentation is imprecise, because there is no file-type checking done,  the function does not validate what it is handed or what it returns, as my actual example proves.  The function is working with  a string and lexically wrong in doing it. If it was behaving as help implies it would spit up on a path terminated with a "/" character because that is indeterminate.  Consistency would be to behave as the UNIX dirname comment would ... i.e. $ dirname "`pwd`/"
/Volumes/home/username